A program for Windows that plays the Block game of dominoes?
I would be grateful for recommendations of a program that meets the following criteria:



I can play a version of the Block game of dominoes against it offline.




It runs on Windows.




It doesn't require a smartphone.




It can be downloaded and installed for free without Google or the Microsoft store being involved at any stage.



Many thanks in advance!

What does this mean? Are you looking just for a game, a bot that plays a specific game (link to it), anything else?
